# jQuery dialog doesn't close from code behind after a Response.TransmitFile

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dialog, download

My problem is that using the quoted aspx page when i call the closing Dialog from Code Behind the dialog doesn't close.
If i comment the Response Transmit file part of code then the dialog properly close, else the download starts but the dialog remains opened.
Let me know if you have some suggestions, thanks!

ASPX PAGE:

```
<%@ Page Async="true" AsyncTimeout="30" Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register src="CreateUI.ascx" tagname="CreateUI" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <%--JQuery--%>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#jobDone').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: true,
                title: "Job completed",
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                }
            });
        });

        function showDialog(id) {
            $(function () {
                $('#' + id).dialog("open");
                return false;
            });
        }

        function closeDialog(id) {
            $(function () {
                $('#' + id).dialog("close");
                return false;
            });
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <!-- ScriptManager to manage UpdatePanel -->
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="mainScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <!-- CreateUI Component -->
    <uc1:CreateUI ID="CreateUIForm" runat="server" />

    <!-- Hidden Field to pass data -->
    <asp:Table ID="TableMain" runat="server" CssClass="table">
        <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
            <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" runat="server">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="UI_Paths" runat="server" />
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>

    <!-- div linked to Jquery dialog -->
    <div id='jobDone'>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelDownload" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelMessage" runat="server" Text="Operation ended successfully, do you want to download the produced files?</br></br>"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonDownload" runat="server" Text="Yes" Width="50px" onclick="ButtonDownload_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonNo" runat="server" Text="No" Width="50px" OnClientClick="closeDialog('jobDone'); return false;" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>            
    </div>        

</asp:Content>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
private void DownloadFile(object uiPaths)
{
    UIGEN config = (UIGEN)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("UIGENGroup/UIGEN");
    string toPath = config.sharedPath;
    if (!toPath.EndsWith(@"\"))
        toPath += @"\";

    string[] fileNamePaths = uiPaths.ToString().Split(new char[] { '*' });

    string zipName = toPath + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_").Replace(" ", "_") + ".zip";
    SharpZipLib.CreateZip(zipName, null, fileNamePaths, SharpZipLib.FolderOffset.LastDirOnly);

    try
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(zipName);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
        Response.Flush();
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        //To do ...Manage the error
    }

    //Delete zip from Server Shared Folder
    if (File.Exists(zipName))
        File.Delete(zipName);
}

protected void ButtonDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        DownloadFile(UI_Paths.Values);
    }

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), UniqueID, "closeDialog('jobDone');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.
The problem is that Response.End(); End the response before the resisted javascrip in ButtonDownload_Click is executed.

I tried the suggested solution (read in other similar threads) to change Response.End() into context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() but the download doesn't start that way.

So i deleted:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), UniqueID, "closeDialog('jobDone');", true);
```

from ButtonDownload_Click and i modified the aspx page from this:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDownload" runat="server" Text="Yes" Width="50px" onclick="ButtonDownload_Click" />
```

to this:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDownload" runat="server" Text="Yes" Width="50px" OnClientClick="closeDialog('jobDone');" onclick="ButtonDownload_Click" />
```

This way the ButtonDownload suddenly close the dialog from javascript then execute the server side ButtonDownload_Click performing the download.